# "is not a function error" in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to call function testAlert() by 'Alert' button click.

Component code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { Radio } from './radio.model';
import { RadioService } from './radio.service';

import '/app/rxjs-extensions';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'radio',
    templateUrl: 'radio.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'radio.component.css' ]
})

export class RadioComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() radio: Radio;

    errorMessage: String;

    constructor(
        private radioService: RadioService,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  testAlert()  {
    console.log("Hi!");
  }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getRadio();
    }

    getRadio() {
        this.radioService.getRadio()
            .then(
                radio => this.radio = radio,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }

  /*
   * Sent Radio setting to Dropwizard server and then to C server
   */
  save(): void {
        this.radioService.updateRadio(this.radio)
            .then(() => this.goBack());
    }

  /*
   * Sent Radio setting to Dropwizard Rest Container
   */
  saveRest(): void {
    this.radioService.updateRadio(this.radio)
      .then(() => this.goBack());
  }


    goBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
 }
```

View code:

```
<div *ngIf="radio">
    <div>
        <label>Frequency, GHz: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="radio.freq" placeholder="freq"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>TX Power, dBm: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="radio.power" placeholder="power"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>RSSI, dBm: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="radio.rssi" placeholder="rssi" readonly/>
    </div>
  <div>
    <label>Type: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="radio.type"  placeholder="type"/>
  </div>
    <button (click)="save()">Apply</button>
  <button (click)="saveRest()">Ok</button>
    <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="testAlert()">Alert</button>
</div>
```

When i click to 'Alert' button i get the following error:

> "EXCEPTION: Error in
>   http://localhost:9090/app/radio/radio.component.html:22:2 caused by:
>   self.context.testAlert is not a function"  core.umd.js:3491:13 Error:
>   Error in http://localhost:9090/app/radio/radio.component.html:22:2
>   caused by: self.context.testAlert is not a function  (unknown)
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.context.testAlert is not a function 
>   core.umd.js:3493:17 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:  core.umd.js:3496:17
>   anonymous/View_RadioComponent0.prototype.handleEvent_4@/AppModule/RadioComponent/component.ngfactory.js:80:21
>   DebugAppViewhttp://localhost:9090/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12783:28
>   decoratePreventDefault/<@http://localhost:9090/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js:3223:55
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:9090/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:275:21
>   NgZonehttp://localhost:9090/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4401:32
>   ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:9090/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:274:21
>   Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:9090/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:28
>   ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:9090/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:28
>   core.umd.js:3497:17 ERROR CONTEXT:  core.umd.js:3500:17 Object {
>   _view: Object, _nodeIndex: 4, _tplRow: 22, _tplCol: 2 }

I tried to change name of method  'save()' that works correct to 'save1()'. Nothing changed. Button that called 'save()' method work correct. It seems like my project code is not changed after i make some changes in code.

What can it be?

Comment: Is that the correct html? Does the other functions work?

Comment: check changing to `testAlert():void  {
    console.log("Hi!");
  }`

Comment: is your view code in radio.component.html ?

Comment: @echonax It's kind of strange, but all functions work correct except testAlert() and saveRest(). The html file is correct.

Comment: @ParthGhiya yes, of course.

Comment: @MansiParekh just tried. The same result.

Comment: This error occurs when the name of the methods called in an event not matched with the template declaration and inside the class.

Comment: I created temp project and copy pasted your code, with minor changed, like empty radio service class. Yet, it works great. testAlert gets called everytime. I am using @angular/cli and following version
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10